# Does this PDO process look protected from SQL injection?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-injection

Does this process look protected from SQL injection attacks?

Is there something I could possibly change to make it more protected?

```
<?php
  include("../include/database.php");

  if(isset($_POST['details']))
  {
    $values = $_POST['details'];

    $param1 = htmlspecialchars(trim($values['param1']));
    $param2 = htmlspecialchars(trim($values['param2']));

    $conditions = [];
    $parameters = []; 

    if (!empty($param1))
    {
        $conditions[] = 'COLUMN1 LIKE ?';
        $parameters[] = $param1."%";
    }
    if (!empty($param2))
    {
        $conditions[] = 'COLUMN2 = ?';
        $parameters[] = $param2."%";
    }

    try {
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $select = "SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM table";

        if ($conditions)
        {
            $select .= " WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $conditions);
        }          

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($select);
        $stmt->execute($parameters);

        $out = array();

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $out[] = $row;
        }

        echo json_encode($out);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $conn = null; 
  }
?>
```

Comment: It looks safe but it's twice the size it should be. For example in your other question you were using fetchAll() but now for some reason you don't

Comment: You are intentionally looking for a literal `%` at the end of the second param? `$param2."%";`  And a separate question: what is the desired query if someone wants to search for the string `0`?

Comment: @YourCommonSense - Are you referring to another question I asked on StackExchange?  In regards to not using fetchAll(), I wasn't thinking about it.  I wrote the script using fetch() and I got back the necessary results.

Comment: @mickmackusa - Yes, I was allowing the user to type in just a few letters.  I'm not entirely sure what you mean about searching for the string 0.  Would you please elaborate?

Comment: What does your code do? I get you're looking for vulnerabilities when interacting with SQL but a short description goes a long way. Additionally site policy is to be a short synopsis of your code, not what you want out of a review. Please [edit] your code to ammend these issues.

Comment: Is this only the target of an ajax call?  You are not writing to the database.  Do you need to use POST?  Do you actually mean to use LIKE on both conditions in the WHERE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your script is part of a basic ajax searching technique.

- `$_POST` is typically used when writing to the database (or when there is a distinct reason that `$_GET` is unsuitable). Since you are merely SELECTing data, just use `$_GET`.
- if you are going to validate your incoming data, don't bother acquiring resources until after you have validated the incoming data and determined that it qualifies for a trip to the database.  If you are going to default to SELECTing the whole table, then it doesn't matter.
- it looks like if params 1 and 2 are missing, you are happy to perform a full table SELECT.  So why deny the full table SELECT if `details` isn't declared?
- `empty()` is greedy -- it is looking for any falsey value.  Even the string `0` - which has a length of 1 - is deemed empty. Perhaps do a `strlen()` check instead.
- I don't think that trimming should be forced on the data if part of a search string -- maybe the user wants to include the space.
- don't `htmlspecialchars()` as an attempt to improve security.  The prepared statement is going to protect you from string injections.  This call should be used when printing to screen, not querying the db.
- I think you have a typo in your second WHERE condition in that you mean to use a second LIKE but you have used `=` and kept the `%` appended to the value.
- I recommend that you design your table names and column names as lowercase strings to differentiate them from MYSQL keywords.
- you are not performing an data manipulations on the result set in this layer, so it will be more direct to `fetchAll()`
- always provide a response string from this script; ideally every response should be json so that your response receiving script can be simpler.
- never show end users the raw error message. Give them a vague indication of an error and nothing more.
- As @YourCommonSense commented, you should move your `$conn->setAttribute` call your include file.
- Normal execution of your script will not be generating any errors.  Catching the errors will prevent the logging of the errors.  I recommend removing the try catch block.  For continued researching, [start here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/227420/141885).

Code:

```
$conditions = [];
$parameters = [];   

foreach (['param1' => 'COLUMN1', 'param2' => 'COLUMN2'] as $param => $column) {
    if (isset($_GET['details'][$param]) && strlen($_GET['details'][$param])) {
        $conditions[] = $column . " LIKE ?";
        $parameters[] = $_GET['details'][$param] . "%";
    }
}

include("../include/database.php");
$select = "SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM table";
if ($conditions) {
    $select .= " WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $conditions);
}          
$stmt = $conn->prepare($select);
$stmt->execute($parameters);
echo json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

---

In your ajax call, do not tell declare the response type as `html` -- it's not html, it is json.  In doing so, you won't need to `parse` it.

Comment: Two corrections if you let me: `setAttribute` should be moved to database.php. PDOException **must** be logged and for this purpose and error is better to be served by a centralized error handler than a direct catch

Comment: I am absolutely certain that you know more and are far more passionate about appropriate error handling than me.  Are you intending to edit my post? Or wanting me to? I don't want to accidentally override your edit.

Comment: I forgot to advise about `$_GET` over `$_POST` when reading from the database.  I am spending time with my wife right now, so I'll edit later.

Comment: I didn't think about editing, just thought the comment would serve as well. and yes, I agree about $_GET for the search.

Comment: Maybe it would be best if you posted an answer to talk about the error reporting. I don't think I can predict your preferred handling.  I think I'd like to see it.  In my own project, I would only want a handling technique that would not damage the UX.  This way you can advise about the `setAttribute()` placement as well -- which I fully agee with.

Comment: I am getting a 500 error.  Trying to diagnose...

Comment: My bad -- semicolon inside of `$response`.  And as YCS said, please move `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` to inside your include file.

Comment: Actually, I think I found the problem. In the foreach, where $param => $column, I don't think $column is being set.  When I print the array, it looks like this:  

 Array
(
    [0] =>  LIKE ?
    [1] =>  LIKE ?
)

Comment: Should I just post a question on StackOverflow?

Comment: @JohnBeasley you are correct.  Fixed that too.  Nah, don't bother posting on SO, it's my responsibility to fix my dodgy snippet.

Comment: Updated per your suggestion, and the conditions are now showing the columns, but I am still getting a 500 error. Still diagnosing...

Comment: I'll be awake for a few more minutes.

Comment: The error seems to isolated to this part:  $response = [
                'status' => 'success',
                'data' => $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            ];  I can comment out 'data' => $stmt->fetchAll(PDO:FETCH_ASSOC); and I am getting 'success' in the console.

Comment: Yes, I have corrected that line in my answer.  See the unwanted `;` after fetchAll()?

Comment: Well, I removed the semicolon, and I was no longer getting any errors.  Problem is, I wasn't getting any data back either.  I happened to change your $response = [] over to what I originally had using the while(), and then passing the $out variable.  I indeed get data back using the while().  Does that make sense?

Comment: Regarding: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62134103/2943403 You need to be informing your ajax call to expect `json` not `html` -- then you won't need to `parse` the return value.  Also, you will need need to check that `status` property before trying to access the `data` property (subarray) of the response.  I'd like to know the feedback from your XHR tab of Developer tools.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57166562/change-datatable-cell-background-function - The way I return the datatable in that question is similar to how I'm returning the datatable in this case.

Comment: @JohnBeasley I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Everything works like a charm.  I do appreciate it.

Comment: Well, I need inspiration to write a good answer but this birdie is hard to catch and you never know when it dawns on you. Luckily it clicked though for the different question.  @JohnBeasley please see my answer to the other question, which is largely  applicable to your case in regard of general error reporting, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/243749/101565